# Duplicate a document on elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I need to clone the content of a document in my elasticsearch index (in the same index) by using the kibana console. I need exactly the same fields in the _source of the document (of course, the copy will have another id). I tryed to:

1. GET the document
2. Create a new empty instance of document
3. Update the new document by
   manually copying the properties of the result on (1):

> ```
> POST /blog/post/VAv2FWoBKgnBpki61WiD/_update {    "doc" : {
>   "content" : "..." ...
> ```

But the problem is the field contain veeeery long properties. And sometimes I got an error since the strings seem not to be scaped when I manually copy them from the Kibana interface.

I searched in the documentation but I can not find a query to duplicate a document, and it is a quite common think to do I think...

Any clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of [Reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html). Here is what you can do.

### Summary of steps:

- Create a `destination_index` (dummy). Make sure the mapping *is exact* to that of `source_index`
- Using [Reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html), reindex **that** particular document from `source_index` to `desitnation_index`. During this operation, update the _id (I've mentioned the script)
- Reindex this document back from `desitnation_index` to `source_index`

### Reindex Query

**Step 1: Copy document from source_index to destination_index. (With the script)**

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "source_index",
    "query": {
      "match": {
        "_id": "1"
      }
    }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "destination_index"
  },
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._id=2",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}
```

Note how I've added a `script` in the above query that would change the `_id (_id is set as 2)` of the document. Your destination_index would have all the fields with exact same values as that of source except for the `_id` field.

**Step 2: Copy that document from destination_index to source_index**

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "destination_index",
    "query": {
      "match": {
        "_id": "2"
      }
    }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "source_index"
  }
}
```

Now search the `source_index`, it would have two documents with different `_ids (_id=1 and _id=2)` having exact same content.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Of course it helps. I also found another alternative by using a logstash script :)